# sfml 2 and cmake building

Tags: c++, cmake, sfml

Hello I am trying to use sfml 2 with codeblocks. I have followed this tutorial http://www.sfml-dev.org/tutorials/2.1/compile-with-cmake.php. I have done everything in tutorial and now I need go to sfml-build folder and in terminal run make and after I run it I got this error:

```
[ 38%] Building CXX object src/SFML/Window/CMakeFiles/sfml-

window.dir/Linux/WindowImplX11.cpp.o
make[2]: *** No rule to make target `/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libGL.so', needed by `lib/libsfml-window.so.2.1'.  Stop.
make[1]: *** [src/SFML/Window/CMakeFiles/sfml-window.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Comment: Did you installed OpenGL as it is asked inside the tutorial ?

Comment: vedran@Vedran-HP:~/Documents/sfml-build$ glxinfo | grep "OpenGL version"
OpenGL version string: 4.2.12217 Compatibility Profile Context 12.104

Answer (score 1):

SOLUTION:

I had previously installed glew1.5 and that didn't let me to install glew1.7 needed by SFML2.1.

And I needed to install this two:

```
sudo apt-get install libxmu-dev
sudo apt-get install libxi-dev
```